# How to get image pixel brightness and contrast in OpenCv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

How to get the brightness and constrast of range of pixel and apply it to set a gradient on another image in opencv c++?
I've tried to do that with this code 
but I didn't get a good result

I want to apply the brightness and constrast of second part of image1 to the first part of image2 to apply an gradiant. the final goal is to stitch the two images

[image]

```
Mat image = imread("1.jpg" );
Mat image2 = imread("2.jpg" );
const int darkness_threshold = 128;


cv::Mat hsv;
cvtColor(image, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
const auto result = cv::mean(hsv);

cv::Mat hsv2;
cvtColor(image2, hsv2, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
const auto result2 = cv::mean(hsv2);

cout<<"resultat1: "<<result<<endl;
cout<<"resultat2: "<<result2<<endl;


Mat new_image = Mat::zeros( image.size(), image.type() );
double alpha = result2[0] - result[0]; 
double beta = result2[2] - result[2];      
for( int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ ) {
        for( int c = 0; c < image.channels(); c++ ) {
            new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
              saturate_cast<uchar>( alpha*image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] + beta );
        }
    }
}
namedWindow("New Image",WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("New Image", new_image);
namedWindow("Image2",WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Image2", image2);

imwrite("imgs1.jpg",new_image);
imwrite("imgs2.jpg",image2);
waitKey();
return 0;
```

Comment: So you wanna learn a brightness percentage of an image and apply the same percentage to other image?

Comment: We can help you better if you could show the original image, the output image, and the desired output image. It's not totally clear what your problem is